# Jmeter plugin to report functional tests in maven

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have never used JMeter or Maven and have been assigned to the task in my work place. I have JMeter Functional tests which are integrated with maven and when I run it from maven they run fine and produce a result like below:
However, the approach is okay if all tests are green. If something fails I don’t know which test run has failed. Can we do something to improve the reporting of maven from JMeter.
I saw something called jmeter-analysis-Maven-plugin which I believe is to analyze performance test results from JMeter. Any idea or any other plugin you know to report functional tests of JMeter in a better way.
Also one more question. If we have to use this analyze plugin do I need to download the jar file of the plugin. But where to keep it. Is there any guide which explains how to use a new JMeter plugin with maven from scratch?

```
[INFO] Tests Run: 7, Failures: 0
[INFO] Total time: 25.714 s
```

Comment: Tried to use jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin.

It analyzes only performance, not the results. So not sure what can be used for functional testing. Even have tried to use a workaround by using stylesheets using extras in jmeter but that is cool, but its not something which can be integrated into the automation run.

Comment: JMeter is a performance testing tool so most things built around it are designed to report on performance stats.  I wouldn't have thought JMeter would be particularly good for functional tests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no super-user-friendly tool, which presents equivalent of Java stack trace for JMeter functional tests failures. What you may need to do, is to either manually load JTL file in JMeter or parse it with other tool, to get the failure details.